# Difference between dataframes with same ID pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 Dataframes like this:

```
ID Date1
1 2018-02-01
2 2019-03-01
3 2005-09-02
4 2021-11-09
```

And then I have this Dataframe:

```
ID Date2
4 2003-02-01
4 2004-03-11
3 1998-02-11
2 1999-02-11
1 2000-09-25
```

What I would want to do is find the difference in dates (who have the same ID between he differences in dataframes) using this function:

```
def days_between(d1, d2):
    d1 = datetime.strptime(d1, "%Y-%m-%d")
    d2 = datetime.strptime(d2, "%Y-%m-%d")
    return abs((d2 - d1).days)
```

and summing up the differences for the corresponding Id.

The expected output would be:
Date is the summed up Differences in datewith corresponding ID

```
ID Date
1 6338
2 7323
3 2760
4 13308
```

Comment: Can you add expected ouput?

Comment: @jezrael Thanks nearly forgot about it I did it now

Comment: Is df1 always unique and it's only df2 that can have duplicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution if `df1.ID` has no duplicates, only `df2.ID` use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for new column used for subtracting by [`Series.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html), convert timedeltas to days by [`Series.dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html) and last aggregate `sum`:

```
df1['Date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date1'])
df2['Date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date2'])


df2['Date'] = df2['ID'].map(df1.set_index('ID')['Date1']).sub(df2['Date2']).dt.days
print (df2)
   ID      Date2  Date
0   4 2003-02-01  6856
1   4 2004-03-11  6452
2   3 1998-02-11  2760
3   2 1999-02-11  7323
4   1 2000-09-25  6338

df3 = df2.groupby('ID', as_index=False)['Date'].sum()
print (df3)
   ID   Date
0   1   6338
1   2   7323
2   3   2760
3   4  13308
```

Or use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) instead `map`:

```
df1['Date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date1'])
df2['Date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date2'])


df2 = df1.merge(df2, on='ID')
df2['Date'] = df2['Date1'].sub(df2['Date2']).dt.days
print (df2)
   ID      Date1      Date2  Date
0   1 2018-02-01 2000-09-25  6338
1   2 2019-03-01 1999-02-11  7323
2   3 2005-09-02 1998-02-11  2760
3   4 2021-11-09 2003-02-01  6856
4   4 2021-11-09 2004-03-11  6452

df3 = df2.groupby('ID', as_index=False)['Date'].sum()
print (df3)
   ID   Date
0   1   6338
1   2   7323
2   3   2760
3   4  13308
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
d = pd.merge(d1,d2)
d[['Date1','Date2']] = d[['Date1','Date2']].apply(pd.to_datetime, format = '%Y-%m-%d')
d['Date'] = d['Date1'] - d['Date2']
d.groupby('ID')['Date'].sum().reset_index()    
    ID       Date
0   1   6338 days
1   2   7323 days
2   3   2760 days
3   4   13308 days
```